# In Nunjucks, how to conditionally output a line?

Tags: nunjucks

I want to output a line conditionally in nunjucks, but don't want to have an empty line if the condition is false.

Example:

```
Before
{{ 'Something' if false }}
After
```

renders like this:

```
Before

After
```

I would like to remove the empty line without lowering the readability of the template. Is there a nice way to do that?

I would expect something like `{{- 'Something' if false }}` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Nunjucks has it's own conditional methods. Note the percent symbol instead of double moustaches.
https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#if

```
{% if hungry %}
  I am hungry
{% elif tired %}
  I am tired
{% else %}
  I am good!
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I believe the OP idea was to remove the empty line, not really about the `if` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can conditionally output {{"\n"}} to get what you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).